# Persistent Object defined by a CronJob on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, cron-task, object-persistence

I have a report that takes too long to be assembled, so I would like to make a CronJob (with rufus scheduler gem) to **generate the report after midnight** when there´s **no traffic** on my application.

The question is: do I need to save the result of the **CronJob** routine in a DB table or can I have it by mantaining it on a Global Variable for example. Is this possible? Is this usual and safe?

The objective is to have the report **without using de DB**. So I would generate an (lets say) array with all the daily data of the report, and with the UX I would manipulate my report as I want without messing with my DB that makes my server (AWS) get loaded and slowing down the entire website. That way, my controllers would use the **Persistent Array** to generate the reports and my server will keep running fast.

Comment: why don't you save it in a file on your server? I am saving some reports in a file (but not consulting it via UI) and then sending me some daily and weekly summary to check if the scheduler is still alive

Comment: It is an alternative... Is your reports very heavy do be made like mine? I have like 100 entries and sometimes i think maybe there could be a way out of this... but except from the report, my app is smoking fast...  lol

Comment: well i'm just opening to users my application, so i still cannot evaluate with precision how big my report will be, but in my case is just to check scheduler is up and running well.

Comment: I runderstand... its ok.. ill try some alternatives. thanks for the suggestion.